# Flash connecting to a WCF service

Tags: flash, wcf, json, actionscript, rest

I would like ask for guidance on the proper endpoint configuration for my WCF service to enable a Flash app to consume it.

Thanks,
Keith Rull

Comment: perhaps you could start by adding some more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you should start with a [webHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412176.aspx) and naturally you need to apply the [webHttp behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924425.aspx) as well. Then you just need to figure out what serialization format you want to work with. Flash can do JSON or XML, so you need to decide which you prefer and then you set the [ReqeustFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute.requestformat.aspx)/[ResponseFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute.responseformat.aspx) properties of the [WebInvokeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute.aspx) which are applied to your operations.

Comment: Can Flash consume Web Services with WS-* specifications?

Comment: Flash cannot normally consume web services with WS-* specifications, since they are specific to WCF. In reply to Drew, webHttpBinding implies a REST service rather than a SOAP service. Since there are many examples of how to call SOAP services from Flash, I would go with SOAP rather than REST.

Comment: WS-* specifications are not specific to WCF, they are standards. WCF is just Microsoft's implementation on those specifications. Also, I know webHttpBinding is REST and that's why I recommended it because is comes with a lot less baggage than SOAP and therefore should be much easier to get going with in Flash. Not to mention the same services could be consumed easily by a pure AJAX client as well.