# How to call wcf function from as3

Tags: flash, wcf, actionscript-3, json

I have been cosuming webservices using alducente.services.WSDL classes with old ASP.NET services from Flash.

Trying the same as3 calls with the new WCF services I get the error that the method I am calling  does not exist.

According to [Flash connecting to a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614157/flash-connecting-to-a-wcf-service) I have declared the function on IService as follows

```
<OperationContract()> _
    <WebInvoke(UriTemplate:="Sub?x={x}&y={y}", BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Xml)> _
    Function Subtract(ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
```

but that fixed nothing. Also I tried putting on web.config the  tag but is not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's hard to tell from just the detail you've provided. If you don't mind, can you provide some more info?

Here is what I suggest:

- Enable tracing on the service side, generate tracing logs, and analyze with SvcTraceViewer. To do this, follow the instructions at [this MSDN article on using the service trace viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx).
- Turn on debug exceptions. This is done by turning in includeExceptionDetailInFaults, which [you can do by following the instructions here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/david_bennett/archive/2006/11/12/how-to-turn-on-debug-exceptions-with-wcf.aspx).

Once you do this, you should plenty of more info on what's going funky at the service side. Can you please share once you find out? We can go from there.