# WCF, Flash,Webservice

Tags: wcf, flash, web-services

How can WCF service will communicate to a flash object , request will be sent from flash and response will be sent to flash.. what will be a the return type of any method in teh webservice and type of parameters..

Answer (score 0):

Your Flash code will simply call the WCF service method, which will return a data structure that contains its response. The Flash code then reads the fields in that response.

See also [Flash connecting to a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614157/flash-connecting-to-a-wcf-service) and http://forums.adobe.com/thread/834538.